# WriteFile and Sprint in C for Windows

Tags: c, windows

I'm basically trying to make this code work in windows and I have to use the sprint() and writefile() functions included in the windows API. I'm a little confused as to how to go about this, the windows C code seems a lot more complicated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//Defining String used for name//
#define NAME "Rodger Rodger"
Main(){
char tbuf[35];
memset(tbuf, '\b', sizeof(tbuf));
sprintf(&tbuf[0], "Hello %s\n", NAME);
write(1,tbuf,sizeof(tbuf));
}
```

Output: Hello Rodger Rodger

This works however I need to do it in Windows using the writefile() and sprint() functions.

EDIT: Managed to do it in the end. This is the final code:

```
//C Programming in Windows //
//Timothy Ford //
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>


//Defining String used for name//
#define NAME "Timothy Ford"

int main(){
char tbuf[35];

//Handle used to define output
HANDLE Outta = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

//DWORD used to store bytesWritten
DWORD written;

memset(tbuf, '\0', sizeof(tbuf));
sprintf(tbuf,"Hello %s\n", NAME);

//WriteFile used for output of string
WriteFile(Outta, tbuf, sizeof(tbuf), &written, NULL);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see two errors in your code, that are unrelated to your problem (whatever it is): Your main function should be named `main` (note lower case `m`); As per the C specification `main` must return an `int`. Besides that, _what_ is your problem? Are there errors compiling? Is the output not what you expect (please edit question to include expected and actual output)? Something else?

Comment: Where is the `sprint` function in WinAPI? Did you mean `sprintf` in C standard library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice several problems with your code:

- Don't pass the address of `tbuf[0]` to `sprintf`. Instead pass tbuf. Tbuf is already a pointer to character string: `sprintf(tbuf, "Hello, %s\n", NAME);`. Not that it will not work as is but I think the version I propose is both shorter and clearer.
- Why are you memsetting tbuf to '\b'? This is backspace while I believe you want to set tbuf to 0('\0')

Here is the working version on [ideone](http://ideone.com/2tXaI).

Comment: Thank you for that, any ideas in terms of getting the same output on Windows using the sprint() and writefile() functions?

Comment: I don't think there will be any difference. This IS your code, I only used `int main` instead of Main to get the code to compile. I am using sprintf and write just like you do.

Comment: @TimothyFord You really don't need to call `memset` to "clear" the buffer you are using. `sprintf` will automatically add a string terminator to the buffer so you can use `strlen(tbuf)` instead of `sizeof(tbuf)` (using the last might print out weird characters, or in the case of having backspaces in the buffer, will remove some or all of your output).

Comment: One more thing - in order to compile the code on ideone I had to replace all the quotes with regular `'` and `"`.

Comment: Hmmm, I've been using gentoo linux and the gcc compiler and it was compiling fine in current form and given expected output. In terms of how running it on windows, it simply doesn't work. I've been told to re-write it using the aforementioned functions but C code for windows just seems far more complicated.

Comment: Hi, in response to compiling on gentoo with gcc, I recommend to use -Wextra -Wall flags and if you're really brave -pedantic.

Comment: I believe that because sprintf() is a low level system call, various OS's change it.